# How to get client IP from http request?

Tags: c++, http, get, request

I'am using HTTP SERVER API 1.0.
And get Request(PHTTP_REQUEST) from remote machine. 
I've tried get Address (*HTTP_TRANSPORT_ADDRESS::pRemoteAddress*) from struct *PHTTP_REQUEST* using ***inet_ntop***, but returned value is not valid.
How to get client IP from PHTTP_REQUEST?

Comment: Are you implementing the complete HTTP yourself, or are you using an existing library that does that for you? If you're using a library, what library do you use? And please provide the (relevant) code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
std::string ipAddrv4(sockaddr *addr)  {
    String IP = "";
    IP = std::to_string(int(addr->sa_data[2] & 0xff));
    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        IP += "." + std::to_string(int(addr->sa_data[i] & 0xff));
    }

    return IP;
}
```

Comment: When there are functions to do this in a protocol-independent way (like `inet_ntop` mentioned in the question) why implement someting like this? We don't even know what the actual problem is that the OP is having, so this might not even solve it.